# SQL query finding entries that lies close to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a database with columns of x, y positions. I wanted to get a list of all entries that contains another entry within 5 unit values of proximity to any other entry in the database. The distance between 2 entries can easily be calculated by Pythagorean theorem. But I am unsure how to loop through all the other entries to test whether it lies in the region of an object inside the database. It is a similar concept as using SELECT-ing DISTINCT in SQL, but I want to allow some error/flexibility to match with the other entries. What is a way to do this using SQL query?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack research effort.

Comment: when you say the keyword "loop" i know you haven't done enough research about mysql. I won't give a direct answer but what you might want to look in is how to process your data with a query before displaying and how to use `...HAVING field=value` syntax. Do some research and come back when you KNOW what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You want all rows for which at least one other row with the distance exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T1.ID != T2.ID     -- never match with itself
                AND (T1.X - T2.X) * (T1.X - T2.X) +
                    (T1.Y - T2.Y) * (T1.Y - T2.Y)   <= 5 * 5)
```

The same can be done with a join, but then you would get multiple results if there are multiple other entries within the distance.
This might be what you want (if you want to get the data of both entries), or you could use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM MyTable AS T1
JOIN MyTable AS T2 ON T1.ID != T2.ID
                  AND (T1.X - T2.X) * (T1.X - T2.X) +
                      (T1.Y - T2.Y) * (T1.Y - T2.Y)   <= 5 * 5
```

Both of these queries will match the same entry twice, once in `T1` and once in `T2`.
If you want to avoid getting two results, replace `T1.ID != T2.ID` with `T1.ID < T2.ID`.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume you have a table with fields `id`,`x` and `y`. And assuming that `id` is unique so the query to list ids of elements like you described should be :

```
SELECT a.id FROM positions as a, positions as b WHERE a.id <> b.id AND ((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)) < 25;
```

Hope this helps